# Integral remainder in multivariable Taylor expansion.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I was curious about how Taylor's theorem works for functions $f :\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and I found these formulas [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor%27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions).

$${\begin{aligned}&f({\boldsymbol {x}})=\sum _{|\alpha |\leq k}{\frac {D^{\alpha }f({\boldsymbol {a}})}{\alpha !}}({\boldsymbol {x}}-{\boldsymbol {a}})^{\alpha }+\sum _{|\beta |=k+1}R_{\beta }({\boldsymbol {x}})({\boldsymbol {x}}-{\boldsymbol {a}})^{\beta },\\&R_{\beta }({\boldsymbol {x}})={\frac {|\beta |}{\beta !}}\int _{0}^{1}(1-t)^{|\beta |-1}D^{\beta }f{\big (}{\boldsymbol {a}}+t({\boldsymbol {x}}-{\boldsymbol {a}}){\big )}\,dt.\end{aligned}}$$

I was confused by the remainder term since if I try to apply it in dimension one and I take the multi-index $\beta = (2)$ (so this would simply be a $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ case) for example then in front of the remainder I would have $\frac{2}{2!}=1$ (because $|(2)|=2$) but when I look at the the formula in 1D I get a factor $\frac12$ in the remainder. I must interpret something wrong.